# Pathological function needed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Give a differentiable function that has a positive derivative at $0$,
>   yet is *not* increasing on any open neighbourhood of $0$.

I believe that the required function needs to have a derived function that is discontinuous at $0$ (ie. the required function needs to be not continuously differentiable at $0$). Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice title!   $\hskip4in$

Comment: Functions of the form $Ax^\alpha+Bx^\beta\sin(x^\gamma)$ are your friends for these types of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Example 3.5](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA37&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Gelbaum and Olmsteads' *Counterexamples in Analysis*:

The function $f$ defined by
$$f(x)=\cases{x+2x^2\sin(1/x),& $x\ne0$\cr 0, &$x=0$}$$
  is differentiable,  $f'(0)=1$, but $f'$ takes both positive and negative values in every neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thanks! $f'(x)=1+4x\sin\frac1x-2\cos\frac1x$ in every punctured neighbourhood of $0$. How to show that this derived function takes both positive and negative values in every punctured neighbourhood of $0$ ?

Comment: @Ryan $f'(1/(k\pi) ) =1+0-2=-1$ if $k$ is even and $f'(1/(k\pi) ) =1+0+2=3$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know how I would've solved this problem on my own. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan You're welcome. Glad to help. (I think you'd have eventually found it, using Ross' hint.)

Comment: Insertion for super-explicitness: For each neighbourhood $N$ of $0$, there is some odd $k_1$ and some even $k_2$ such that $\frac 1{k_1\pi},\frac1{k_2\pi} \in N$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you need something that wiggles faster and faster as it gets near zero, so it has a decreasing part in every neighborhood of zero.  Can you think of a common example?

Comment: @Ryan Think about wiggling along the line $y=x$.